# Changing a class in real time

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I have the following `ui-select` directive that uses a class `abc`. I need to make variable the `min-width` but since it's within a class I cannot use `ng-style` to change it. I cannot use `ng-class` either as the `min-width` element is fixed. Any ideas?

```
<style>
.abc > .dropdown-menu{
min-width:40px;
}
</style>

<ui-select ng-model="selected.value" ng-disabled="disabled" class="abc" >
</ui-select>
```

Comment: `ng-style` should add an inline style that has a higher specificity than your class, changing the `min-width` value like you want. Why would you want to change the class itself?

Comment: as previous commenter, why can't you use `ng-style` or `ng-class`? You can use both of them.

Comment: `ui-select` is a directive (see [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/#examples)) and the only way I can change the style is by assigning a class (abc in my example) and specifying a style for .dropdown-menu. What I am trying to do is to use `ng-style` instead of the class, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using `min-width: inherit` on the child class.